# jQuery custom menu - adding and removing classes onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

If someone can think of a better title for this question, please feel free to alter it. This is the issue: in a navigation menu, clicking an item should mark it red (default is orange). Both orange and red styles (class names `bmark` and `bmark_active` respectively) were generated using the CSS Button Generator application. This is the jQuery code which should do the job:

```
$(function () {
    $('.bmark').click(function(){
        $('.bmark_active').addClass('bmark');
        $('.bmark_active').removeClass('bmark_active');
        $(this).addClass('bmark_active');
        $(this).removeClass('bmark');
    });
})
```

It works fine for all buttons, except the default one ('All' in the fiddle example). So if you click 'Russia', for example, the red focus will move onto that button (by removing orange class and adding red class), but then when you click 'All' again, it doesn't switch to red. Why is that and how do I fix it?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52esG/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not applying the `click()` event to the parent element, only applying it to the child elements:

```
$(function () {
    $('.bmark, .bmark_active').click(function(){
        $('.bmark_active').toggleClass('bmark').removeClass('bmark_active');
        $(this).addClass('bmark_active').removeClass('bmark');
    });
})
```

**[jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/52esG/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You're not binding on the '.bmark_active' element.

You can do this :

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.bmark_active,.bmark', function() {
        $('.bmark_active').addClass('bmark').removeClass('bmark_active');
        $(this).removeClass('bmark').addClass('bmark_active');
    });
})
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8QLJ/)

But most often I'd prefer to give the same class to all elements, and to only add or remove a class on the active elements, so that the event handling code would be

```
 $('.bmark').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');
```

It also lets the CSS be cleaner as your two classes are, for now, mostly identical and it's better to have just the few changes between the two modes isolated in the 'active' class.

Answer (score 1):

Updated your fiddle do it that way. More simplified.  The other answers here work fine but this is the least verbose way of handling it.

```
$(function () {

    $('.bmark').click(function(){
        $('.bmark').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
   });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chazelton/52esG/2/